# Data retrieval from saved instance to serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

(Django 2.0, Python 3.6, Django Rest Framework 3.8.2)

I wanted to know how to retrieve data that's been saved as an instance in a separate model, and include it in a different serializer as a selection field. For example, let's say I have the following models:

```
class Colors(models.Model):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique = True)

    RED = 'RED'
    BLUE = 'BLUE'
    GREEN = 'GREEN'
    YELLOW = 'YELLOW'
    ORANGE = 'ORANGE'

    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        (RED, 'red'),
        (BLUE, 'blue'),
        (GREEN, 'green'),
        (YELLOW, 'yellow'),
        (ORANGE, 'orange')
    )

    favorite_colors = models.CharField(
        max_length=6, choices=COLOR_CHOICES
    )




class PickFromSpecifiedColors(models.Model):

    #THIS IS PART OF WHERE MY PROBLEM LIES
    #TO ACHIEVE WHAT I WANT, I DON'T KNOW IF I NEED TO IMPLEMENT THAT LOGIC HERE
    #OR IN MY SERIALIZER

    colors_user_id_7_selected = models.ForeignKey(Colors, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And user with id=7 created the following post in `Colors`:

```
{
    'id': 7
    'email': 'example@example.com',
    'favorite colors': 'red','blue','green'
}
```

When I go to `PickFromeSpecifiedColors` to post, I would want to see the following options as a selection field which restricts the choices to only what user with id=7 provided:

```
{
    'colors_user_id_7_selected': 'red','blue','green'
}
```

Where users 1 through 6 may have different favorite colors.

How would I set up my model and serializer to obtain this result? I've tried nesting serializers, but that only allowed a user to post new favorite colors and not retrieve the favorite colors of some other specific saved instance.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your models also?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner can do, just made the edit

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. Django REST has no idea about selection Field widget. You need to put `validator` in your field